# Could not load NIB in bundle Xcode8

Tags: ios, swift, view, swift3, xcode8

I've followed a tutorial but when I try to run my code it crashed because it couldn't load NIB in bundle.

Here's my code:

```
class BuyPremiumView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

// MARK: - Private Helper Methods

// Performs the initial setup.
fileprivate func setupView() {
    let view = viewFromNibForClass()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [
        UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth,
        UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight
    ]
    addSubview(view)
}

// Loads a XIB file into a view and returns this view.
fileprivate func viewFromNibForClass() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
}

}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Okay as a quick update, I tried doing the same steps in a separate Project and it worked there but it doesn't work when I try to do it in the project I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

if you would load view from nib i think best easy way is :

```
   var yourView : YourView =  NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("myXib", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! YourView
```

i hope this help

Comment: Where would you type this in? And would you replace this code with some of my code?

Comment: you can replace this line : ` let view = viewFromNibForClass() `with ` var yourView : YourView =  NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("myXib", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! YourView `  , yourView equal to view ,

Comment: Unfortunately it also doesn

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either but thank you